# HTM5 LocalStorage : Save a game process for every logged in player

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developping a html5 game but i got this problem if a player is in the mid game and accidentally closes the web browser. Once he  opens the game again, the game starts from the
beginning and the game that the player was playing is lost. so i found this solution With the local storage, we can encode the entire game data into JSON and store them. In this way, players can resume their game later.

But in my game every player has a login , so i should store his login too in the localStorage so every player will have  his own localStorage .

So Can'i do this with localStorage ? 
Is there a better solution?

Thank u in advance

Comment: Every player already has its own localStorage, it's local. So the data you save is kept in the user's computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use SQLLite database on client. it is open source and could be downloaded from [download link for SQLLite](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 1):

Depending the size of your data, you may use a cookie. It is faster and more simple.

Comment: If you feel the answer helped you then please accept the answer so that it can help others as well